# Host .NET MVC 3 Website on ASP .NET 4.0 Host

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

Is it possible to host my .NET MVC 3 Razor website on a hosting service that states they host ASP .NET 4.0 sites but not explicitly .NET MVC 3?

If so what things must I consider? E.g. Are there additional Assemblies I will need to include in the deployment etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

You simply need to find out if they have deployed the MVC 3 DLLs.  If they haven't or you don't feel like checking you can simply include them in your project.  Then when you publish your application all of the required MVC DLLs will be copied into your bin directory.

- Right-Click your MVC project in VS
- Select "Include Deployable Dependencies"
- Select the MVC 3 Razor Option

This creates a dll_deployable folder that contains all of the DLLs to be included in your project when you publish.